# Не воспроизводится звук wav в jar

Tags: java, javafx, аудио

Пытаюсь воспроизвести звук в приложении. При запуске из IntelliJ IDEA все работает, но когда собираю артефакт jar и запускаю его, то в нем звука нет. В чем могут быть проблемы?
Код:

```
// воспроизведение звука
private void SoundPlay(int second) throws URISyntaxException {
    soundCountdown = null;
    soundEnd = null;

    try {
        InputStream bufferedIn1 = new BufferedInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("number.wav"));
        InputStream bufferedIn2 = new BufferedInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("null.wav"));

        AudioInputStream aff1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn1);
        AudioFormat af1 = aff1.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info1 = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af1);

        AudioInputStream aff2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn2);
        AudioFormat af2 = aff2.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info2 = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af2);

        // звук 0 секунд
        if (second == 0) {
            if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info2)) {
                soundEnd = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info2);
                AudioInputStream ais2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn2);
                soundEnd.open(ais2);
                soundEnd.start();
            } else { System.exit(0); }
        }

        // звук 3, 2, 1 секунд
        if (second <= 3 && second != 0) {
            if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info1)) {
                soundCountdown = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info1);
                AudioInputStream ais1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn1);
                soundCountdown.open(ais1);
                soundCountdown.start();
            } else { System.exit(0); }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Ошибка воспроизведения звука!");
    }
}
```

Лог

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at com.sun.media.sound.RIFFReader.read(RIFFReader.java:125)
    at com.sun.media.sound.RIFFReader.<init>(RIFFReader.java:60)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.internal_getAudioFileFormat(WaveFloatFileReader.java:65)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(WaveFloatFileReader.java:55)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:117)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
    at main.WindowController.SoundPlay(WindowController.java:299)
    at main.WindowController.ShowImagesAction(WindowController.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Ошибка воспроизведения звука!
```

[image: Иерархия при распаковке jar]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с загрузкой файлов, попробуйте `URI...` заменить на `InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("number.wav"));` и потом `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedin);`

Comment: @0x666c, таким образом и в студии не воспроизводит, переходит в `catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка воспроизведения звука!");
        }`

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста в *catch* `e.printStackTrace();` и запустите оригинальный jar командой `java -jar xxx.jar`, если будет исключение, то впишите его в вопрос

Comment: @0x666c, добавил исключения и иерархию распакованного jar. Кстати картинки подгружаются идентичным способом и прекрасно работают.

Comment: Дело в том, что звуковые файлы по идее нужно грузить в виде потока (*InputStream*), а у вас они грузятся просто как ресурсы. Попробуйте переписать код для соответствия написанному мной.

Comment: @0x666c, обновил код и вывел лог. Странно, почему поток закрыт, если я его даже и не закрываю нигде?

Comment: ругается на строчку `AudioInputStream aff1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn1);`

Comment: Попробуйте поставить слеш (/) перед именами файлов, если не заработает, то я опубликую полностью переписанный код в ответах.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Теперь ошибка `javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я переписал ваш код, чтобы он работал:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent.Type; // Классов Type в jdk много, поэтому указал верный


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        new Main().soundPlay(0);
    }

    static class AudioListener implements LineListener { // Слушатель окончания звука,
                                                         // без него прога завершится сразу
                                                         // после начала проигрывания. (clip.start();)
                                                         // (не завершится если дальше будет код).
        private boolean done = false;
        @Override public synchronized void update(LineEvent event) {
          Type eventType = event.getType();
          if (eventType == Type.STOP || eventType == Type.CLOSE) {
            done = true;
            notifyAll();
          }
        }
        public synchronized void waitUntilDone() throws InterruptedException {
          while (!done) { wait();}
        }
      }

    private void soundPlay(int second) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            // Чтение при помощи потоков, прямо из jar 
            // (+ слеш т.к без него скомпилированная прога не работает.)
            InputStream bufferedIn1 = new BufferedInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/number.wav"));
            InputStream bufferedIn2 = new BufferedInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/null.wav"));

            AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();

            if (second == 0) {
                AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn1);
                if( !AudioSystem.isLineSupported(new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat())) ) System.exit(-1); // Всё в одной строке

                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.addLineListener(listener); // Добавление слушателя.
                clip.open(ais);
                clip.start();
                listener.waitUntilDone(); // Пауза до окончания клипа (звука).
            } else if (second <= 3) {
                AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn2);
                if( !AudioSystem.isLineSupported(new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat())) ) System.exit(-1);

                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.addLineListener(listener);
                clip.open(ais);
                clip.start();
                listener.waitUntilDone();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ошибка воспроизведения звука! Надеюсь это не напечатается :)");
        }
    }
}
```

В комментариях есть подсказки, класс *AudioListener* честно взял отсюда: [Trouble playing wav in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577724/trouble-playing-wav-in-java/577926#577926).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!